# No response on jquery.click()

Tags: jquery, html

May I know why with the following when I'm clicking on the button the `alert('clicked')` does not appear?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Base64.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#Button1").click(function () {
                alert('clicked');
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="input" action="">Username:
            <input type="text" id="username" value="" />
            <br />Password:
            <input type="text" id="password" value="" />
            <br />
            <input type="button" id="Button1" value="Submit" />
            <div>Login Test 1.htm</div>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You really should indent your HTML.

Answer (score 6):

When the script executes, the button doesn't exist in the DOM yet. Wait until the DOM is ready with `jQuery.ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Button1").click(function(){alert('clicked');});
});
```

Alternatively, you can run the script somewhere after the button is added:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Base64.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="input" action="">Username:
            <input type="text" id="username" value="" />
            <br />Password:
            <input type="text" id="password" value="" />
            <br />
            <input type="button" id="Button1" value="Submit" />
            <div>Login Test 1.htm</div>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#Button1").click(function () {
                alert('clicked');
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: i was under the impression that $ is already the shorthand for $(document.ready)

Comment: @kyrogue: It is when you pass a function. `jQuery()` is overloaded to do a variety of different things. But yes, you could change the `$(document).ready(` to simply `$(`.

Comment: @kyrogue - `$(function() { // Code here });` is the document.ready shorthand.

Answer (score 3):

try this ,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Button1").click(function(){
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is ASP.NET mentioned anywhere in this question?

Comment: fixed, could of swore I saw asp:Button

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/69v27/4/

Please try sourcing Jquery in your code like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
```

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#Button1").click(function() {
        alert('clicked');
    });

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You should surround the jQuery statement with `$(function() { ... });`